# How to add delete cascade on staging table

Tags: sql, postgresql, cascade

Here how I created tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A(
  id uuid NOT NULL, UNIQUE
  name text
);


CREATE TABLE TABLE_B(
  id uuid NOT NULL, UNIQUE
  name text
);

-- custom realization of many-to-many association
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A_B(
  id uuid NOT NULL, UNIQUE
  a_id uuid REFERENCES TABLE_A(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  B_id uuid REFERENCES TABLE_B(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I've already created tables and now can't update it by adding ON DELETE CASCADE.
And I need now to add ON DELETE CASCADE to staging table TABLE_A_B. How to do it ?(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A_B(
  id uuid NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  a_id uuid REFERENCES TABLE_A(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  B_id uuid REFERENCES TABLE_B(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=69452f16a05c525bf42f23b0f6d56e45) is a db<>fiddle that fixed some typos in your code.

In particular, the foreign key reference should be to a *primary key*.  Although allowed to a unique key, the purpose of primary keys is really to identify individual rows -- and one main use is for foreign key references.

EDIT:

If the constraints already exist, then do the following.

First, get their names:

```
select *
from information_schema.table_constraints
where constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' and table_name = 'table_a_b';
```

Note:  You can assign names to skip this step.

Then drop the existing foreign key constraint:

```
alter table table_a_b
    drop constraint table_a_b_a_id_fkey;
```

Finally, add a new one:

```
alter table table_a_b
    add constraint fk_table_a_b_a
        foreign key (a_id) references table_a(id)
            on update cascade
            on delete cascade;
```

Comment: I've already created it. Now I can't up update it by adding on delete cascade

Comment: @D.Nursultan . . . Drop the existing constraint and add a new one.

Comment: can u please illustrate it